# how do I mount usb drive to a container/pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, automation, udev

I am working on a kubernetes project at them moment. right now the application is broken up into several pods. The current ask is to spin up a new pod with priviledged rights, and use it to dynamically detect and mount usb drives to the pod from the host machine.

I have tried using a udev rule that gets copied to the pod, the problem is the udev rule does not trigger in the pod. I have the same udev rule on the host machine with the same rights, and pathed the same way and it does trigger there.

If anyone has any suggestion or help it would be beneficial. Thank you.

Comment: Kubernetes typically runs in a multi-host clustered environment; which host has the USB drive?  How does the cluster know?

Comment: It is not a typical task and isn't a good idea to do that, because kubernetes was not designed to to that... Even if you find a way, you need to know in what host your pods was placed and manage this task will require a huge effort. Do you considered work with [Persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)?